# How to configure database first Entity Framework 6.1 and .NET 4.5.1 with Sqlite?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sqlite

With Microsoft dropping SQL Server Compact from Visual Studio 2013, I've decided to move my application to SQLite.  However, when I try to create the O/RM from an existing database, I receive the following error message:

> Your project references the latest version of the Entity Framework; however, an Entity Framework database provider compatible with this version could not be found for your data connection

I am using the following technology stack:

- windows 7 64 bit
- Visual Studio 2013 Professional
- NuGet Package for Entity Framework 6.1
- NuGet Packages SQLite 1.0.92.0, SQLite 1.0.92.0 Core, SQLite 1.0.92.0 EF6, SQLite 1.0.92.0 LINQ
- Installed `sqlite-netFx451-setup-bundle-x86-2013-1.0.92.0` which allows the VS2013 designer to work with SQLite

I'm using a new C# console application.  I've tried rebuilding the application, rebooting, and re-installing everything short of the OS.

Both the "Platform Target" on the Build property page and "Platform" on the configuration manager are set to x86.

Comment: See my answer for SQLite 1.0.93.0 and EF 6.1.1 here (with video) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089346/database-first-create-entity-framework-6-1-1-model-using-system-data-sqlite-1-0

Answer (score 0):

The exception message is quite clear.  You have not provided a database provider that is compatible with Entity Framework.

> Your Program -> Entity Framework -> Database Provider -> Database Services

Doing a quick Google for `Entity Framework Sqllite provider` yielded:

[System.Data.SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) - Not sure if it's been updated for EF 6.1

and

[dotConnect for SqLite](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/) - Might be compatible.

Comment: While I appreciate the discussion, this does not answer the question.  Since posting this, I've tried to get this to work with EF 6.0.2 without success.  I will keep at it; however, I hope someone had managed to get this combination working or provide a combination that will work.

Comment: The question was `How to configure database first Entity Framework 6.1 and .NET 4.5.1 with Sqlite?` I fail to see how not stating what is needed (Sqlite Database Provider) with possible providers doesn't solve the problem.  Maybe you need help with typing the provider name that works in the config file's provider name, by changing `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"` to the provider name you decide to use?