# System.Data.SQLite design-time integration with VS 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, nuget, system.data.sqlite

I have installed the [System.Data.SQLite.Core](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core) package with NuGet as described in the System.Data.SQLite at [FAQ: (5) Is there a NuGet package?](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/faq.wiki#q5).

How can I enable the design-time support in Visual Studio 2013?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you got it to work, but for me your steps were only half the story.
A lot of additional fiddling around was required to generate an EDMX.
Posted the steps here:
[Database first create entity framework 6.1.1 model using system.data.sqlite 1.0.93](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089346/database-first-create-entity-framework-6-1-1-model-using-system-data-sqlite-1-0)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, at least as of version 1.0.93, the NuGet packages do not provide the designer components.

Only the bundle available on the [System.Data.SQLite Download Page](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) installs the necessary components:

[sqlite-netFx451-setup-bundle-x86-2013-1.0.93.0.exe](https://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.93.0/sqlite-netFx451-setup-bundle-x86-2013-1.0.93.0.exe)

> This setup package features the mixed-mode assembly and will install all the necessary runtime components and dependencies for the x86 version of the System.Data.SQLite 1.0.93.0 (3.8.5) package. The Visual C++ 2013 Update 2 runtime for x86 is included. The .NET Framework 4.5.1 is required.
>   **This is the only setup package that is capable of installing the design-time components for Visual Studio 2013.**

[image: Setup]

And now the option is available when adding a connection:

[image: sqlite]