# An unexpected error occurred in .NET framework data provider for SQLite

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I want to use `SQLite` with Entity Framework. I installed the `SQLite` and did some specific changes in my `app.config` file. I can see the `SQLite` option in the data provider list.

When I select, it asks a connection string. After I write the connection string get the error saying :

> An unexpected error occured in .NET framework data provider for SQLite

Regards, Mehmet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite 1.0.9xx and EF 6.1.xx are very finicky to set up. Please see if my answer here works for you (be sure to watch the video) : [Database first create entity framework 6.1.1 model using system.data.sqlite 1.0.93](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089346/database-first-create-entity-framework-6-1-1-model-using-system-data-sqlite-1-0)