# Sync oracle database to a kind of local database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, oracle, entity-framework

I have a central oracle database and I need to write a c# desktop app that can hold all the oracle data for being offline, works on the data and than sync it back to oracle later. The local database should be simple and should not need admin rights to install and use, actually like SQL Compact Edition, which is unfortunately deprecated)

I want to use a modern software architecture, so I thought about using EF 6.0 and generate some entities to work on.

I've read tons of documents and threads, but it seems that almost everything is deprecated. All tutorials I found are made with Visual Studio 2008. Newest version of Microsoft Sync Framework is 2.1 and the additional Microsoft Sync Framework Toolkit was released three years ago with no updates. It also uses Microsoft SQL Compact Edition 4.0, which is deprecated ([comment by Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902854(v=sql.110).aspx)).

I found an example syncing Oracle and SQL CE on `code.microsoft.com Database-Sync-Oracle-and-037fb083`), but it uses the old and deprecated `System.Data.Oracle` namespace.

Somethings that's not deprecated is SQL Server 2014 Express and LocalDB, but it needs admin rights to install and hundreds of Megabyte on the disc)

Also SQLite is up to date and can handle this, but unfortunately there seems to be no EF 6.0 support. [Here is a nice overview about it](http://erikej.blogspot.de/2011/01/comparison-of-sql-server-compact-4-and.html)

Is there anybody out there who knows some "news" about it?

Comment: Just as a point that others up-vote it, Using `XML` with adding some functions to handle queries over them (XML-Query) can be a solution? ;).

Comment: You can use SQLite with EF:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089346/database-first-create-entity-framework-6-1-1-model-using-system-data-sqlite-1-0

Answer (score 0):

Finally i used Access with typed datasets. I'm not happy with that. SQLite was the only real option, but there are also no good viewer to see and edit the data. The customer is good with Access, so we used that.

Unfortunately i have two different technologies to use databases in my application. EF for oracle and typed datasets for access... this is poor. nobody knows why microsoft has no modern solution for that, without admin rights and hundreds of megabyte. Also EF can not use Access, whyever. Maybe they want everything in a cloud...